# CentOS only detecting 50% of ram

Tags: linux, centos, memory

I have 16GB ram in my machine. Before, free -m outputted the normal 16 GB ram, however now (after a reboot) it only detects 8 GB ram. Is one ram module damaged?

grep -i memory /var/log/dmesg outputs

`Memory: 15621184k/16017200k available (2535k kernel code, 387120k reserved, 1748k data, 196k init)`. (Which looks like 16 GB to me).

`free -m` outputs:

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7484       7415         68          0       6104        524
-/+ buffers/cache:        786       6697
Swap:         2055          0       2054
```

Anything I might be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the outputs from `dmidecode`, `uname -a` and `lshw`

Comment: Does the BIOS see the RAM as 16GB or 8GB?

Comment: @Tom O'Connor: i've put the `dmidecode` in Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6166898/dmidecode.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait wait - you say "I'm using the server as a Xen HVM (DomU)".

Do you mean that this domain is dom0 (the main instance)?

If so, then yes, your dom0 memory shrinks when you start up domU domains.

Use `xentop` to see how much memory is actually there and to whom it's allocated.

To change the allocation, use the command:

```
xm mem-set <domainid> <memorysize>
```

Comment: That's correct. Stupid of me to not to mention in my initial post. Thanks =). However, do you any way to return the not used memory from the balloon (as they call it) to the system memory?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following to see what `dmidecode` reports for installed RAM.

`dmidecode -t 17` will show the DIMM population per slot.

The following will output the total RAM.

`dmidecode -t 17 | awk '( /Size/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) { x+=$2 } END{ print "\t" "Installed Ram: " x "MB"}'`

```
[root@bootylicious ~]#  dmidecode -t 17 | awk '( /Size/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) { x+=$2 } END{ print "\t" "Installed Ram: " x "MB"}'

        Installed Ram: 65536MB
```

Comment: Thanks, it outputs: `Installed Ram: 16384MB`. I'm using the server as a Xen HVM (DomU). I always had 16 GB but since a reboot (?) I have 7356 MB according to `free -m`.

Comment: Run `top`. What is listed as your `MEM` amount on the fourth line of the output? Did you dedicate 8GB of RAM to Xen?

Comment: I think I got it, when using Xen - when you create a VM it will 'reduce' your memory. I now have 6 GB left. I deleted two VM's and my memory hasn't risen yet, however I think it may take some time?